# Insert entity with persist : cannot be null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entity "OneToOne" with Symfony : "charge" and "ecriture" :

**Charge entity :**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="LogicielBundle\Entity\Ecriture", inversedBy="coproprieteCharge", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $ecriture;

    public function setEcriture(\LogicielBundle\Entity\Ecriture $ecriture)
    {
        $this->ecriture = $ecriture;
        $ecriture->setCoproprieteCharge($this);
        return $this;
    }
```

**Ecriture entity :**

```
<?php
class Ecriture
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="LogicielBundle\Entity\Copropriete\Charge", mappedBy="ecriture", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $coproprieteCharge;

    public function setCoproprieteCharge(\LogicielBundle\Entity\Copropriete\Charge $coproprieteCharge)
    {
        $this->coproprieteCharge = $coproprieteCharge;
        return $this;
    }
```

And I Have very simple form with imbrication :

**ChargeType :**

```
<?php
class ChargeType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ecriture', new EcritureType, array(
                'label' => false
            ))
        ;
    }
```

This Controller is very simple : just call "New Charge()" beacause I think Ecriture insert with "persist" in entity comment.

But I have this error " *SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ecriture_id' cannot be null* " ; I don't understand beacause "ecriture" insert with "persist"

Comment: Thanks, Yes I have, with "doctrine:schema:update --force"

Answer (score 0):

`OneToOne` is represented only by one join column and it is the one on the field where you use `inversedBy`. There you specified, that this column is not nullable. As you probably did not set instance of `Ecriture` to your new instance of `Charge` entity it stays null and that is violation of `nullable=false` that you specified.

Cascade persist does not mean, that a new instance of entity is created by the entity manager, if it has not been set for not-nullable field. The entity managaer may not know how to create one (e.g. entity can have constructor with required parameters).